# trying to get the number of products with same product id

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a product table with columns ..

```
product_id 
product_name
prodcut_description
```

Now I want to find the how many number of products with one product_id (I mean like how many number of products in stock like that).

Do I need to add any table for counting the products with same id like stock? If so , how do i get the number products with same id in stock

I am using c# and winforms.

**EDIT :**

this is my code where i am binding database

```
      var products = from prods in tsg.products
                       select new
                       {
                           productid = prods.product_Id,   //0                            
                           productnam =  prods.product_Name, //1
                           productimage = prods.product_Image, //2
                           productprice = prods.product_Price,//3
                           productdescr = prods.product_Description, //4                               
                       };

        productbindingsource.DataSource = products;
        productgridview.DataSource = productbindingsource;
```

Comment: please rielaborate your question and tell us the SQL you would like to execute, I suppose is a product_id, Count(*) from ... Group by product_id. Please confirm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say your table is named products, then the following

```
products.GroupBy(x => product_id).Select(gr => new { Id = gr.Key, Count = gr.Count() }
```

should yield a enumeration with a structure { Id: ProductId, Count = #Produkts in table products with Id ProductId }

Comment: i have to got count as integer along with productname and product id because i want to represent this in datagrid view.. would you pls help

Comment: you can change the code above to add ', Productname = gr.First().product_name' behind the Count or in between. This will give an additional property "Productname" in the anonymous class. I think that the Datagrid should be able to handle those but I'm not totaly sure. If not you have to declare a DataTable with the properties yourself and use "new MySummaryTable { Id = ... }" instead of the "new { Id = ... }"

Comment: i am not able to find this one   var productsbycount = tsg.products.GroupBy(x=> product_id)

Comment: isn't this another question at all? What do yo mean by allign - put Id in the first column, Name in seconds and so on? There is no count at all ... and: is this code working? Yes? Then the new problem is, that the columns are shown in a different order? If I'm right please reconsider searching for a similiar question here (there are a lot) or opening a new question

Comment: ah .. you have to bind the "productsbycount" to your "productbindingsource" instead of your *old* "products" - but please keep in mind that the other parts of your query where not in mine - you have to attach the other fields/properties/columns as well.